# How to backup indexes in Solr 4.9?

Tags: solr, backup, replication

I've installed and configured the last Solr release - Solr 4.9.
It contains more then 10000000 articles and it works perfect at the moment.
But I worried about data loss and I want to back up my Solr indexes so that I can recover quickly in case of catastrophic failure.
I've waste a lot of time to find solution or great documentation but without result.

I've added following strings in my solrconfig.xml:

```
<requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler" > 
   <lst name="master">
     <str name="replicateAfter">optimize</str>
     <str name="backupAfter">optimize</str>
     <str name="confFiles">schema.xml</str>
     <str name="commitReserveDuration">00:00:10</str>
   </lst>
   <int name="maxNumberOfBackups">2</int>
</requestHandler>
```

and opened following url in browser:

```
http://mydomen.com:8983/solr/#/collection1/replication?command=backup&location=/home/anton
```

but backup wasn't created.

What's wrong in my configuration? Can I make a backups by cron?

Regards, Anton.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it through cron, is to simply back up the data folder of the collection as well as the instance folder with all the configs. If you take the data folder and stick it into another collection with same config it will work fine.

However I am not sure what the impact is if Solr is running at the time of backup, you may want to experiment with that.